# A result about commuting matrices in $ M(n, \mathbb{C} ) $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $ A $ be a matrix in $ M(n, \mathbb{C} ) $ and let $ A^{*} $ be its Hermitian adjoint. Suppose that the matrices $ A $ and $ AA^{*}-A^{*}A $ commute. Show that $ AA^{*} = A^{*}A $.

Here is a sketch of my solution :

Lemma : Let $ F $ be a field of characteristic $ 0 $ and $ S,T \in M(n, F) $. Suppose that $ ST-TS $ commutes with $ S $. Then, $ ST-TS $ is nilpotent.

We have that $ A $ and $ B = AA^{*} - A^{*}A $ commute, so by the lemma, $ B $ is nilpotent. Also, $ B^{*} = AA^{*} - A^{*}A = B $, so $ B $ is Hermitian. But, $ B $ being both, nilpotent and Hermitian $ \implies $ $ B=0 $ $ \implies $ $ AA^{*} = A^{*}A $

I was wondering whether there is a simpler solution as mine uses some machinery. Any hints please?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is a good one. Another one is:

Since a hermitian matrix is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis, we may assume that $AA^*-A^*A=diag(\lambda_1I_{n_1},\cdots,\lambda_kI_{n_k})$ where $n_1+\cdots+n_k=n$. Thus $A$ has the form $A=diag(U_1,\cdots,U_k)$ and $AA^*-A^*A=diag(U_1U_1^*-U_1^*U_1,\cdots,U_kU_k^*-U_k^*U_k)$. Finally $\lambda_iI_{n_i}=U_iU_i^*-U_i^*U_i$, that implies $\lambda_i=0$ (cf. the trace) and we are done.

Comment: It should be explicitly mentioned here that the only "machinery" required here is that Hermitian matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: Also, perhaps the step $\lambda I = UU^* - U^*U \implies \lambda = 0$ bears explaining.  I'm not sure what trick *you* had in mind LB, perhaps something with the trace?

Comment: @  Omnomnomnom , about comment 2., you are right. About comment 1., a hermitian matrix is diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Quite elementary, up-voted!
The only reason I wasn't satisfied with my solution is because of the lemma, which, in my opinion, is hard to prove.